# getting a null value while trying to to access a variable's value using Expression Language in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to access a variable's value via JSP's expression language; however, when I check whether the variable is null as in `#{empty name}` I am always getting a null value.

SERVLET CODE:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        //there's no "setParameter" method for the "request" object
        request.setAttribute("name", "TestName");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/hello.jsp");
         rd.forward(request,response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
}
}
```

JSP CODE:

```
    <p> ${empty name} </p>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root to the problem. For some reason I forgot to put the right path of the servlet in the web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the **empty** word.

```
<p> ${name} </p>
```

you actually set `name` on  `request.setAttribute("name", "TestName");` that's  why you need to put proper key, which is `name` to access the value **"TestName"** on your jsp.

Comment: When I do that, I get an empty JSP page. It does not printout the value "TestName".

Any more suggestions would be appreciated...